# Passing value from parameter to SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, parameter-passing, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been digging around the internet, including Stack, for the better part of the morning trying to figure out how to create a parameter and then set its value and pass it into various locations within my where clause in my Oracle SQL. I can't seem to find exactly what I want. it's quite possible that I am not asking the question correctly, so I apologize if this is a redundant question (it seems likely that it is).

Here is the SQL I am running in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code , t.mta_tenure_type_code , COUNT(t.tenure_number_id), SUM(t.area_in_hectares)
FROM   MTA_TENURE t
WHERE
       t.mta_tenure_type_code in ('M','P') AND
       to_char(t.issue_date, 'YYYY') <= '&year' AND
       (
          to_char(t.termination_date, 'YYYY') > '&year' OR
          t.termination_date IS NULL OR
          t.mta_termination_type_code = 'PROT'
       )
GROUP BY t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code, t.mta_tenure_type_code;
```

As you can see, I have '&year' located twice within my query which prompts the user to enter a value each time that variable occurs. The value is always the same year at each variable (i.e. every time the prompt pops up, the user will always enter the same year twice) Being a bit of a python programmer, I had thought that I could make this query more efficient by setting a parameter to '&year' so the user only has to enter it once and the parameter will pass the value into the where clause. Is this even possible? I really thought this would have been an easy google search, but maybe my feeble brain overlooked something. Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm create a procedure with one input argument then use the input value in place of year. Then Execute the procedure.

Comment: I believe in sqlplus `&&` was used to prompt only once for the same variable while `&` prompted each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the `&year` references with `&&year` as @Glenn suggested; see [Avoiding Unnecessary Prompts for Values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-DAEF8542-1042-4F98-9C68-CED90AC42A79) in the SQL*Plus docs (most of which apply to SQL Developer too).

You could also explicitly [define](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/DEFINE.html) the substitution variable, which allows you to [tailor the prompt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/ACCEPT.html):

```
accept year number prompt 'Enter year'

SELECT t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code , t.mta_tenure_type_code ,
  COUNT(t.tenure_number_id), SUM(t.area_in_hectares)
FROM   MTA_TENURE t
WHERE
       t.mta_tenure_type_code in ('M','P') AND
       to_char(t.issue_date, 'YYYY') <= '&year' AND
       (
          to_char(t.termination_date, 'YYYY') > '&year' OR
          t.termination_date IS NULL OR
          t.mta_termination_type_code = 'PROT'
       )
GROUP BY t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code, t.mta_tenure_type_code;
```

or you could define the variable with a specific value so it doesn't prompt at all:

```
define year=2018
```

If you know the value you could also use a bind [variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/VARIABLE.html):

```
var year number
exec :year := 2018;

SELECT t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code , t.mta_tenure_type_code ,
  COUNT(t.tenure_number_id), SUM(t.area_in_hectares)
FROM   MTA_TENURE t
WHERE
       t.mta_tenure_type_code in ('M','P') AND
       to_char(t.issue_date, 'YYYY') <= :year AND
       (
          to_char(t.termination_date, 'YYYY') > :year OR
          t.termination_date IS NULL OR
          t.mta_termination_type_code = 'PROT'
       )
GROUP BY t.mta_tenure_sub_type_code, t.mta_tenure_type_code;
```

Notice the prefix for the variable has changed from `&` to `:`.

You could combine both if you wanted to:

```
var year number
exec :year := &year;
```

... and then use the bind instead of substitution variable in the query.

---

In either case I'd probably either convert the `to_char(...)` value to a number, or use `extract` instead:

```
...
       extract(year from t.issue_date) <= :year AND
       (
          extract(year from t.termination_date) > :year OR
...
```